Can not create logon trigger on AWS RDS sql server instance
In order to audit logins I've used before a server level trigger catching the LOGON and saving it to a table, there are endless examples to do this.
But trying to do the same on and AWS RDS sqlserver instance fails with error Cannot create the trigger 'LogLogons', because you do not have permission.. I've full sysadmin permission. I've read and checked other questions and sites, there are references to mysql and log_bin_trust_function_creators parameter that needs to be enabled and some other things (Can I CREATE TRIGGER in an rds DB?) but for MS SQL Server can't find a confirmation wether server level triggers can be created or not.
Found this but is not clear if logon triggers can be created or not.
CREATE TRIGGER LogLogons ON ALL SERVER WITH EXECUTE AS 'authorized_login' FOR LOGON AS
INSERT DBA.dbo.loginaudit
DEFAULT VALUES;
--DROP TRIGGER LogLogons ON ALL SERVER;


I know about Audits but wanted to first try the common and long used approach that doesn't overcomplicating things creating a parameter group and restarting the service on the console. But as you see on the accepted answer, I was wrong as server-level triggers are just not supported on RDS. So yes, Audit it is.

Amazon's documentation for Amazon RDS for Microsoft SQL Server lists Server-level Triggers under the category of "The following Microsoft SQL Server features aren't supported on Amazon RDS".

Features not supported and features with limited support
The following Microsoft SQL Server features aren't supported on Amazon RDS:
...

Server-level triggers

...

